# Let H be a normal subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $H$ be a normal subgroup of $G$ such that $[ G :H ] = p$, where $p$ is a prime number. Let $K \le G$. Prove that either

- $K \le H$ or
- $G=HK$ and $[K:(H \cap K)]=p$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $K$ is not a subgroup of $H$, then $HK$ has index smaller than $p$ and dividing $p$, hence the index is clearly $1$. Since $H$ is normal, by the second isomorphism theorem we have that $HK/H\simeq K/(H\cap K)$, from which the rest follows.

Comment: Thanks @MattSamuel ! I only couldn't get how does it imply that If $K$ is not a subgroup of $H$, then $HK$ has index smaller than $p$ and dividing $p$

Comment: @Galy $HK$ has larger order than $H$ and the order of $H$  divides the order of $HK$.

Comment: @Galy No problem.